# basic auth respond 500 in postman when it should be OK(Authorized), but 401 Unathorized works fine. using ktor intellij mongodb

Tags: mongodb, authentication, postman, ktor

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlinx.coroutines.channels.LinkedListChannel: method ()V not found

this is my database.kt

> private val client = KMongo.createClient().coroutine
>
> private val database = client.getDatabase("PestaDanDagangDatabase")
>
> private val users = database.getCollection()
>
> private val posts = database.getCollection()
>
> suspend fun getPostsForUser(email: String) : List<> {
>
> return posts.find(Post::members contains email).toList()
>
> }

i'm following some tutorial... getPostsForUser return List of Post data class(it is disappear.. still need to learn to use stackoverflow), the tutorial project is running even i followed the same. i changed the return to be return posts.find(Post::members contains email).toString and the function return String both my code and my tutorial result ok in postman with same respond org.litote.kmongo.coroutine.CoroutineFindPublisher@44fc57b6(except 44fc57b6).

i tried to change the return to be return posts.find(Post::members contains email) and function return type CoroutineFindPublisher of type Post, it is OK in postman but the event time is keep ticking or running.

Comment: Could you provide the relevant code, please?

Comment: yes sure, i just edit my post, i hope it gets  more clear.

Comment: just realized my problem is not about auth..but still.. sorry.

Comment: i just fixed it... i update all the implementation.... before this i reinstsall intellij and ktor,, but not implement. thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered kinda the same problem, but for me the implementation were updated to latest version (as today kmongo 4.4.0 & coroutines 1.6.0), the error was

```
kotlinx.coroutines.channels.LinkedListChannel: method 'void <init>() not found
```

I realized that there was a import conflict with the .toList() method

To solve it I simply, instead of

```
return posts.find(Post::members contains email).toList()
```

used

```
return posts.find(Post::members contains email).publisher.KMongoToList()
```

with as import

```
import org.litote.kmongo.coroutine.toList as KMongoToList
```